# MYSQL using limit in join query to return 1 result

Tags: mysql

im trying to use limit 1 after my query but i'm assuming because of the 'is null' it wont work. I need to check another table to see if the user has seen the item before, so I need to check another table with both the users id and the item id. this is the query.

```
SELECT * FROM item LEFT OUTER JOIN seen on item.id = seen.id WHERE seen.uid is null
```

how can i limit this query to returning 1 result?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item.* 
FROM item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN seen on item.id = seen.id 
WHERE seen.uid is null
LIMIT 1
```

Just add `limit 1` to the end. It should work.

Comment: well thats what thought but when do use LIMIT 1 it doesnt work, ill just have to use an 'if' statement after the query.